# Shopify - Display all discount code in a page

Tags: shopify, discount

I have this code in my Shopify page.

```html
{% for discount in discounts %}
{{ discount.title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

But this is not showing any lists of discount I created. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You know you can only access a Discount object in notifications, like emails? You cannot access them just anywhere. Shopify only exposes that when you need to print an email for example, for the customer to see their items and money they spent.

Answer (score 0):

Discount Object will display a value only if it's accessed in notifications or in the Order Printer App. For more info please refer - https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/discount or https://www.shopify.in/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet